# js 'while' loop doesn't execute code inside

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop

```
var n = 0;

function search() {
    if (document.getElementById('post-6386_119125') == null) {
        if (document.getElementById('show_more_link')) {
            document.getElementById('show_more_link').click();
        }
        window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
        console.log('n is now ' + n);
    } else {
        document.getElementById('post-6386_119125').scrollIntoView()
        n = 1;
        console.log('horray,n is now ' + n)
    }
}

while (n == 0) {
    search()
}
```

so there is some function,that looks for a specific post on news page of social network and if it's not exist for now: it scrolls page down and also pushes a "show next" button if it exists

So…if i go to the console and paste all lines before the loop several times - it all will work fine, but in loop nothing is happening and console goes to infinite count of 'n is now 0'.
I'm new to js, and also got a JQuery plague, so may be I'm missing something very very basic, so excuse me please.

Comment: `n` is never modified in the first if block, so if `document.getElementById('post-6386_119125') == null`, search() will continue to be called recursively.

Comment: Your `if` statement is always true, because you never add a `#post-6386_119125` to the DOM.

Comment: yes, but n is modified in `else` block. So this is point where procces needs to be stopped

Comment: **4castle** I don't need to add this block because it's already somewhere down below in news.

Comment: And I remind, that when I enter code manually in browser console, it works fine. It scrolling a page, and if desired block exists scroll viewport to it.

Comment: What browser are you using? Also where is the javascript in the context of the rest of your code? The fact that it works in the console makes me think it's a timing issue.

Comment: I'm using chrome. I'm running inly in console, to figure out - will it work. That part of code is the only one. Yeah, I think this is something about time. Because when i change  `while` loop to `var searcher = setInterval(function(){
 search();
 if(n==1){
  clearInterval(searcher);
}
 },10)`, it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('post-6386_119125')==null
```

This is always true!

Comment: its' true until `document.getElementById('post-6386_119125')==null` (when post arrive it's != 0)